# How to read and change value from memory in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory

The code inside main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int c_variable = 0; // the target

    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        c_variable += 5; // increase by 5 to change the value of the int
        printf("%i\n", c_variable); // print current value
        sleep(8); // sleep so I have time to scan memory
    }

    return 0;

}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to read the integer `c_variable` and then to modify it inside another .c program. I am on linux so I did `ps -A | grep main` and got the PID of the running program. I then did `sudo scanmem PID` and entered the current value of `c_variable` a few times. I was left with three memory addresses and executing the command `set 500` changed the value the program printed, effectively changing the memory address' value to 500 instead of 35 or whatever the program was currently at. I then executed the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const long unsigned addr = 0x772d85fa1008; // one of the three addresses from scanmem
    printf("%lu\n", addr);

    return 0;
}
```

but I got some random long string of numbers, not the current number. The tutorials and answers I have read on how to read and write memory on linux does not have to use `long unsigned` but can use char* or just int* instead. My memory address seems to be a bit long, I have not see memory addresses that long before. Anyhow, how do I read and write the memory address of the integer `c_variable`?

Edit: the output of scanmem looks something like this

```
info: we currently have 3 matches.
3> list
[ 0] 7771ff64b090,  6 +        1e090, stack, 20, [I64 I32 I16 I8 ]
[ 1] 7771ff64b5d8,  6 +        1e5d8, stack, 20, [I64 I32 I16 I8 ]
[ 2] 7771ff64b698,  6 +        1e698, stack, 20, [I32 I16 I8 ]
3> set 50
info: setting *0x7771ff64b090 to 0x32...
info: setting *0x7771ff64b5d8 to 0x32...
info: setting *0x7771ff64b698 to 0x32...
```

output

```
...
150
155
160
165
170
175
55
60
65
...
```

Comment: You're printing the actual address number, not what is at the address.

Comment: Is the random string of numbers identical to 0x772d85fa1008 or its decimal representation 131037404991496 ?

Comment: Are you aware that the address spaces of two running programs in most current operating systems are separate from each other? The same address can hold different values in different programs.

Comment: @Yunnosch can you refere me to a learning resource where I can read up on this?

Comment: A valid question, but I have to disappoint you. I do not know a recommendable resource.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the actual address number, but in in decimal notation, not what is at the address.

```
const int *addr = (int *) 0x772d85fa1008;
printf("%d\n", *addr);
```

You have to declare `addr` as a pointer type. More specifically a pointer *to an integer*. Its value (`0x772d85fa1008`) holds the *address* of the integer.

Then, in the `printf` call you dereference it to obtain the actual integer stored at the address.

Although in practice I can't vouch for whether this is going to work, since memory in modern operating systems isn't as simple as you make it out to be. But I don't have enough knowledge to assess that.

Comment: I get an error: `cannot initialize a variable of type const int * with an rvalue of type long` since the address is so long. Is it too long? All the tutorials I have seen has been with int, but this address is too long, is it not?

Comment: Try casting the address constant to a pointer before assignment. See my edit.

Comment: @boool3max that causes a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and running the program in sudo causes `Segmentation fault` for all three addresses found. See my edit in post.

Comment: Well there's your answer. Memory between processes isn't that simple

Answer (score 0):

Processes running under Linux generally have their own virtualized memory space. If you want to access memory space of another process, arrangements have been made in the Linux API, see shmctl, shmget, shmat, shmdt.